Sample Keyframe & Smooth Keys in b4.1.1 Missing?
Hi so following video tutorial and can't seem to find in the "Graph Editor" under key tab "Sample keyframes" & "Smooth Keys" seems to have been moved? If anybody knows the workaround that would be great also tried google search found nothing.

There's no link to the tutorial in your post

Yes I did not put a link because I am not focusing on the tutorial just referencing it as the reason why I was looking for this function in b4.1.1, I actually pause the video and noticed the short cut keys which are "shift+alt+O" (Sample Keyframe) and "alt+O" for (Smooth Keys) That were located in the "Graph Editor" under key tab Option list, and That actually worked just wish I knew where these options were relocated to.

Still useful to have the link or even better a screenshot because honestly I don't know what exact feature you mean. This can also increase your chances of getting good answers :) But you already found a solution? Perhaps you can post it as answer so we can close this question.

Blender's frequent changes can be quite problematic, as they require continuous learning. I also encountered this issue and couldn't find a solution other than using the shortcuts. Does anyone know where these functions have been relocated?

Smooth keys is now here: key->smooth->...


Sample Keyframes in Blender 4.22  is called "Bake Keyframes"

